# Laravel and Inertia create route inside Vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I installed Laravel with Inertia. And I got this inside `resources/js/app.js`:

```
require('./bootstrap');

// Import modules...
import { createApp, h } from 'vue';
import { App as InertiaApp, plugin as InertiaPlugin } from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue3';
import { InertiaProgress } from '@inertiajs/progress';

const el = document.getElementById('app');

createApp({
    render: () =>
        h(InertiaApp, {
            initialPage: JSON.parse(el.dataset.page),
            resolveComponent: (name) => require(`./Pages/${name}`).default,
        }),
})
    .mixin({ methods: { route } })
    .mixin(require('./translation'))
    .use(InertiaPlugin)
    .mount(el);

InertiaProgress.init({ color: '#4B5563' });
```

As you may see there is `.mixin({ methods: { route } })`. I can use `this.route('name.of.route')` to generate named route from ˙routes` folder.

I want to modify `route` method to add prefix by default every time route is generated. How do I adjust Inerta's `route` method.

Comment: Where is this { route } comming from? Seems to be undefined in this example, unless it's being defined at ./bootstrap. Are you using Ziggy?

Comment: Not sure really, I installed Laravel with Inertia and I got this

Comment: I have the same and it's not coming from bootstrap.js.. What kind of sorcery is this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> With Inertia all routing is defined server-side. Meaning you don't
> need Vue Router or React Router. Simply create routes using your
> server-side framework of choice.

You can read more about it here (https://inertiajs.com/routing#top)

You've got all the routes available on your javascript installed because of [ziggy library](https://github.com/tighten/ziggy). It provides a JavaScript `route()` helper function that works like Laravel's, making it easy to use your Laravel named routes in JavaScript.

To modify or add prefix to the URL, you'll have to do it from the backend(Laravel) using Middleware or [Route Groups](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-groups), because Ziggy doesn't create URL, it just provides the URL that you define in your Laravel's web.php file in your Javascript.

That's why you have `@routes` in your root blade file. If you remove that, `this.routes` or `this.$routes` won't be available.

E.g.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function () {
    Route::inertia('/dashboard', 'Dashboard')->name('admin.dashboard');
});
```

This means this URL will be available at `/admin/dashboard` and you can access it with Javascript as `this.route('admin.dashboard')`;

Or read more on the Ziggy package to give you the desired result.

> It is worth mentioning that you can name the route with anything you
> like. Just make sure that whatever you pass inside `->name('')` is the
> same thing you use when calling `this.route()`;

Comment: Can't we rename the `dashboard` route name to `admin.dashboard` for example? Bcz when i try to change the `dashboard` route name, it still return error "route dashboard not found" even if i already change the route('dashboard') into `route('admin.dashboard')` in `Welcome.vue`

Comment: @BariqDharmawan you can name the route with anything you like. Just make sure that whatever you pass inside `->name('')` is the same thing you use when calling `this.route()`.